# How can I make a consecutive animation of buttons?

Tags: android, animation

I have a few buttons on a grid. I need that this buttons are animations. The animation is very simple, I only want that this buttons change his color and return o his original color, like a "simon game".
So, my problem is the next:
I have been trying make this with AnimatorSet. I make my own class for the buttons :

```
class Button{

   ObjectAnimator anim;
   public Button button;
   public int colorA;
   public int colorB;

    public Button(){};

};
```

And I have:

```
private Boton[] buttons;
buttons = new Boton[numButtons];

for(int i=0; i<numButtons; i++)
     buttons[i] = new Boton();
```

After:

```
  for(int i=0; i<numButtons; i++){

        buttons[i].animacion=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(buttons[i], "alpha", 1f, 1f);          
        buttons[i].animacion.setStartDelay(1000);
        buttons[i].animacion.setDuration(2000);
        buttons[i].animacion.addListener(new miAnimador(i));

    }
```

Also, I defined my own Listener:

```
class miAnimador implements Animator.AnimatorListener{


    int numBoton;

    public miAnimador(int num){
        numBoton=num;
    }

    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator paramAnonymousAnimator) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        buttons[numBoton].button.setBackgroundColor(buttons[numBoton].colorA);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        buttons[numBoton].button.setBackgroundColor(buttons[numBoton].colorB);
    }
};
```

This is very powerful for me because I can have a vector of buttons and launching his animation when I want.

After I can make this: build a animatorSet with the  sequence of animations that I want.

```
            AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();

            final List<Animator>listaAnimaciones = new ArrayList<Animator>();


            final List<Animator>AnimationsSequence = new ArrayList<Animator>();

            AnimationsSequence.add(buttons[0].anim);
            AnimationsSequence.add(buttons[1].anim);

            //Add list
            s.playSequentially(AnimationSequence);

            s.setStartDelay(5000);

            //Start animation
            s.start();
```

Well, this work well, and I like the form of the AnimatorSet work, but the problem occur when I try animate the same buttons twice.
The exception is: "Circular dependencies cannot exist in AnimatorSet" and i don't understand why this happening.

Be that as it may, I need make this, and I was thinking that this is the best solution, but: 
If this don't work, how can get this?

I accept any idea.

If you thinking  that this is bad solution, please I would like to know your opinion.